# change attributes of parent elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

I have a list with links, so, If i hover a link i want to the color of the background that contains the link changes it's color which class is '.secctabla' .

I'm trying to do this (using velocity.js too that intregrates with jQuery) and it doesn't work (I use also parent() and it don't work either):

```
<tr class="secctabla">
        <td>
          <h3 class="linkCursos"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          <?php
          $argumentos = array(
            //default to current post
            'post' => 0,
            'before' => '<p class=\"meta\">',
            //this is the default
            'sep' => ' y ',
            'after' => '<p class=\"meta\">',
            //this is the default
            'template' => '%s: %l.'
            );
          ?>

          <?php the_taxonomies($argumentos); ?>
        </td>
        <td> 
          <?php $desc = get_post_custom_values("descripcion");
          if (isset($desc[0])) { ?>
            <p class="small"><?php echo $desc[0]; ?></p>
          <?php } ?>
        </td>
      </tr>

$('.linkCursos a').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest("secctabla").velocity({background: '#000000'});
  })
```

Comment: `"secctabla"` is looking for a non-existent `<secctabla>` element; you're looking for an element with that class-name, and should be using: `".secctabla"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.linkCursos a').hover(function() {
    $(this).closest(".secctabla").velocity({rotateZ: "180deg"});
  })
```

I didn't specify the class correctly. This worked well :)